# Mobile Web Framework that will only control rendering and page transitions

Tags: frameworks, mobile, web-framework

I have been using jQueryMobile for a bit now, and there are some things I like about it and others I do not.

First I will give a bit of background.

I have a light weight mobile application that has a few configurations and 6 pages. Ideally I Would like to load all pages into the DOM (they interact with each other quite often and pages will be switched in the same frequency). The application will post for some JSON every ***n*** seconds and refresh the values on the page (yes it is primarily a information display app).

with the jQuery Mobile framework the only real thing I like is how easy it is to have a standardized UI a crossed all devices and browsers, I'm really not using too much else out of the framework other than the basic page navigation (if you are familiar with the framework; a bare-bone multi-page design is all i need).

Why I want to step away from jQueryMobile is how weighty it is. Not only do you need to include the mobile library, but also the base jQuery libraries. This I do not like because I'm not using jQuery anywhere else on the site.

Any suggestions on light-weight mobile frameworks that have a similar rendering as jQueryMobile?

Comment: jQuery libraries + jQuery mobile are, together, less than 100k last time I checked. Is that truly too weighty?

Comment: The short answer is no, however if only a very limited set of functionality is required why include a heavier library.

Comment: ***I could just develop the site from scratch, but I have only one device (Android) to test on***

Comment: Premature optimization is a waste of time :) Optimize your optimization process

Comment: this is not premature... changing a framework half way through development because you are using 2% of it's available functionality is a waste of time.

Comment: I guess it would be a little more clear if I called it a ***Mobile UI Framework*** consisting of event registration and handling and UI widgets.

Comment: I misunderstood. I thought you were optimizing performance - I took weighty to mean it makes the application too large, in which case, if it's not a problem downloading, you're optimizing too early. However, it looks like you mean "inelegant and conceptually messy" - in which case, I won't know if it's too early or not. Re-factoring for elegance and cleanliness is an art.

Comment: Not so much re-factoring either. I'm in the early stages of a mobile UI, I know what I want it to look like. And I can achieve that with jQuery Mobile, however that is all I would be using that framework for is the page transitions and the general UI look (for compatibility and consistency). However the framework offers a lot more than that, and there is no way to strip it out. So i'm left wondering if there is a smaller framework out there that will offer a rich UI, without all of the additional js functionality.

Comment: Would you prefer a framework with only the functions you need, but was the same size as JQuery+Mobile? If not, I think we can say that you object to the size of the lib. I understand how you feel - it does seem wasteful to include the entire lib when you're not using 90% of it, but I'd recommend not spending too much time on replacing the lib unless your current one is _actually_ causing performance problems.

Comment: Never mind - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com/)? It's a 2-5k mobile JavaScript library for modern browsers with a largely jQuery-compatible API, so you can use it with the rest jquery code you have.

Regards,
Tom

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest keeping whatever javascript you might already have and moving to HTML5. Most phone browsers are very compatable (about the same as desktop browsers or better) at using CSS3 and HTML5 elements. Plus, if the feature you are trying to add isn't supported the browser will just ignore it and fall back to default values allowing older phones to still work but without the flashy animations.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [customizable download builder](http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/) for jQuery Mobile. You can get very specific about which pieces you want included, and it generates a package with just the JS and CSS that you need, based on your selections.

There's also [a similar thing for jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download/).

Answer (score -2):

Here is a great (but slightly out of date) [break-down of mobile development frameworks](http://operationproject.com/2011/adventures-in-html5-part-one/).

You should remember that "weight" is just one variable impacting your goal--that goal is almost certainly an app that "feels responsive."  So you have other variables, such as "touch response," "transition fluidity," and "impact on other code."  If you use a framework that takes an extra second to download on a 3G network but the app responds 20% faster you're going to be way ahead.  Also, if you're considering deploying with PhoneGap, you should probably choose something that's developed to take advantage of PhoneGap (jQuery Mobile is, as is Sencha Touch.  I don't know for certain on others)

(In my personal opinion, jQuery Mobile does NOT respond as well as some of its competitors.)